# use an editable template with some form variables

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, templates, text

I am new to C# and would like advise on how to create a text file from a template that has three variables that are assigned by a form submission.  Here is how it would look:
template.txt (var1 = name, var2 = location, var3 = year are place holder in the file)
Example:
My name is var1 and I am from var2 where I lived for var3 years.

Form:
Name:
Location:
Year:

Then that output text file would be the sum of the template and the form variables.

Now I can edit the template to read anything and move the variables where ever I want to create any desired output text base on the template and form input.

I hope I have explained that well enough.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the String.Format method.  You could dynamically generate the text and move around the placeholders to represent the variables.  I'd say make the textboxes an array so you can loop through them when you generate the text file.

```
string name = "Luke";
string location = "ATL";
str = String.Format("Hello {0} from {1}.", name, location);

OUTPUT:
"Hello Luke from ATL."
```

MSDN Docs here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Is it possible for the string "Hello {0} from {1}" to come from a file.  something like str = String.Format(template.txt, name, location) where {0} and {1} are in the text of template.txt?

Comment: Yes, but the String.Format takes in a string as the template.  So load the text into a variable then reference the variable in the method.  In short: String.Format(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\PATH\File.txt"), name, location);

Comment: You will also have to reference the IO namespace.  If you aren't familiar, add "using System.IO;" at the top of the page.